# Help sending multiple arguments in ajax php?

Tags: javascript, ajax, argument-passing

I have a pretty limited experience with AJAX and javascript so hopefully this is easier than it's been for me. 
I'm building a simple upload form, just sending data from a form and then to the js then send that over to the php.
basically in the html (which is generated from a php page):

```
<form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this)" action="#">
<input name="data1" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
```

and the js:

```
function ajaxSubmit(thisform) { 
    results=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var submitdata ="";
    submitdata = "uploadfile=" + thisform.elements['data1'].value
results.onreadystatechange=uploadResult; 
    results.open("POST", "./functions/upload.php",true);
    results.send(formdata);
```

(i've stripped out some of the code to make it shorter)
I need to also send a php variable through, so I imagine I could write the function call as  onsubmit="return songUploadSubmit(this, ".$phpvariable.") but I don't know how to pull it out on the javascript end. I need to know, simply I guess, how to pull $phpvariable and tack it on the end of submitdata variable. or if i'm going about this backwards..
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work:

in html:

```
 return ajaxSubmit(this, $phpvariable)
```

in jscript:

```
function songUploadSubmit(thisform, otherdata)
submitdata = "data1=" + thisform.elements['data1'].value + "&data2=" + otherdata;
```

then I can grab both with _Post in the php file.

Overall just basic missing of some fundamentals like I suspected it might be. Passing multiple arguments.

Comment: With jQuery your *data* would just be `{data1: thisform.elements['data1'].value, data2: otherdata}` without any need to care about the contents and their escaping (if your data1 value contains an & that will cause issues right now)

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot upload files via AJAX.**

`'somefield=somevalue&otherField=othervalue'` is what you want to submit multiple key=value pairs though.

However, ***use jQuery or another framework*** if you are going to do AJAX - otherwise you need to take care of url escaping etc. on your own (use `escape(value)` instead of `value`) and your code looks much uglier.